# Versions child process error

Tags: svn, version

Anyone know why this would happen with versions when I try to create a new bookmark. I know that the file does exists because it works correctly on another machine with Versions installed.

Error in child process: exec of 'ssh' failed: No such file or directory

Comment: I edited the congif file to have the full path and it worked. For anyone having the problem edit this line. ssh = $SVN_SSH /usr/bin/ssh

Comment: The config file in question is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10617648/230167

Answer (score 1):

Chapsterj is right. I just tested it, too. And it was the solution.

I edited the congif file to have the full path and it worked. For anyone having the problem edit this line. `ssh = $SVN_SSH /usr/bin/ssh`