# Where is the user's Subversion config file stored on the major operating systems?

Tags: svn, config, configuration-files

For Subversion 1.7, where is the SVN "config" file located on the various major operating systems (specifically on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux)?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

`~/.subversion/config`
or
`/etc/subversion/config`

for Mac/Linux

and

`%appdata%\subversion\config`

for Windows

Comment: What about setting a proper editor? Could it be also kdiff3 ?

Comment: @pro_metedor See the QA corresponding to [setting the svn editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506653/change-svn-message-editor/).

Comment: My TortoiseSVN 1.9 installation on Windows included a config DIRECTORY, which prevented me running the command line tool. I've removed the directory, replaced it with a FILE, and all seems to be well again in SVN-land.

Comment: In my case : C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Subversion

Comment: @tony497 yep that's equivalent to '%appdata%\subversion\config which can be pasted directly into the explorer address bar.

Comment: Note that the `/etc/subversion/config`  is the *system-level* configuration and the `~/.subversion/config` is the *user-specific* configuration, which overrides settings in the system-wide configuration. The user-specific configuration files are created by the  `svn` command  like `svn --version` if the file does not already exists.

Answer (score 9):

In windows 7, 8, and 10 you can find at the following location

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion
```

If you enter the following in the Windows Explorer address bar, it will take you right there.

```
%appdata%\Subversion
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about Win but n *nix (OS X, Linux, etc.) its in `~/.subversion`

Comment: The common name for UNIX, Mac OSX, Gnu/Linux, is Unix. Note the case. (I think I got the case spelling wrong for OSX). UNIX is a trademark. Unix is a class of operating system.

Answer (score 0):

@Baxter's is mostly correct but it is missing one important Windows-specific detail.

Subversion's runtime configuration area is stored in the `%APPDATA%\Subversion\` directory. The files are `config` and `servers`.

However, in addition to text-based configuration files, Subversion clients can use Windows Registry to store the client settings. It makes it possible to modify the settings with PowerShell in a convenient manner, and also distribute these settings to user workstations in Active Directory environment via AD Group Policy. See [SVNBook | Configuration and the Windows Registry](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/confarea/#svn.advanced.confarea.windows-registry) (you can find examples and a sample `*.reg` file there).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In TortoiseSVN you can access and modify some settings in the context menu "Settings/General" in explorer.

E.g. the "Global ignore pattern" can be edited directly in the dialog box. Such changings are the stored in the registry as bahrep pointed out in her answer.

(Win10/TortoiseSVN 1.13.1, Build 28686 - 64 Bit)