# Where is the SVN default list of ignored files?

Tags: svn, documentation, ignore, filelist

I have googled and search through the documentation. I get stuck on this.

Do you know *where* the list of ignored files by subversion is located  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends - you used to store it in a local file, per user. (either global-ignores section of the config, or registry depending on OS platform).

Now they moved it to a svn property so its [stored in the repository](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/repository-dictated-configuration-day-3-global-ignores). Its called svn:global-ignores and gets used automatically.

Personally, I used to put them in the pre-commit hook and reject any commits with banned file types.

Comment: I wouldn't say that we moved it.  We just added a new property that behaves likes svn:ignore but is inherited by children from their parents.  All 3 of the different methods are combined to determine the ignore list.  https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config

Answer (score 5):

You can find the **default** global file ignore list in the auto-generated user specific config file, in a commented-out line (key `global-ignores` in section `miscellany`). For example, in a file generated by Subversion 1.8:

```
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo __pycache__
#   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store [Tt]humbs.db
```

The file location varies between operating systems; under Linux/UNIX the default is `~/.subversion/config`.

Alternatively, you can directly look for the default ignore list in the Subversion source code archive file (`subversion/include/svn_config.h`, search for `GLOBAL_IGNORE_LINE`).

Example (Subversion 1.9):

```
#define SVN_CONFIG__DEFAULT_GLOBAL_IGNORES_LINE_1 \
  "*.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo __pycache__"
#define SVN_CONFIG__DEFAULT_GLOBAL_IGNORES_LINE_2 \
  "*.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store [Tt]humbs.db"
```

Comment: What is the file location for Windows? (maybe Mac OS too)

Comment: @Stephan, on Mac OSX it should be the same as on Linux, on Windows it is `%appdata%\subversion\config` (cf. [Where is the user's Subversion config file stored on the major operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617826/427158)).